# Sencha - Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP.

Tags: android, extjs, cross-domain

this question asked everywhere but any answers doesn't work to me.

i have a sencha project. project is done but i couldnt opened.

when i try the open in normal (file:///C:/wamp/www/Sencha/iletisim/iletisim/index.html) console giving to me errors :

XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/wamp/www/Sencha/iletisim/iletisim/bootstrap.json. Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP. index.html:1
Uncaught NetworkError: A network error occurred.

but if i trying on the localhost (localhost/Sencha/iletisim/iletisim/) it works fine.

i must convert this project to apk file. but apk file doesnt work on android.
my guess error reason is cross origin. 
how can i fix it and run to android and windows ?

Help me please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make JSONP requests to support cross origin, to do that you need to access that through a proxy or a server side app. On the server side JSON file needs to be wrapped within a callback function.

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy.JsonP